# File upload in servlet corrupts the file

Tags: servlets, file-upload, ajax-upload

I am uploading a file using using ([Valums uploader](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/)) and I using servlet at server side. File type is application/pdf. Code is :

```
String filename= request.getHeader("X-File-Name");
InputStream is = request.getInputStream();
File tmp = File.createTempFile(filename, "");
tmp.deleteOnExit();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tmp);
IOUtils.copy(is, fos);
byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) tmp.length()];
is.read(bytes);
```

Now these bytes are getting stored into database as longblob. But it seems that inputStream in above code is adding some more data in the file thats why file data is getting corrupted. I download the same data as pdf file, found that both- original uploaded file and now downloaded file have the same size, but when the downloaded file is opened in Acrobat, it reports "File is corrupted". For upload request I have used only file input. So there are no chances of other input params in inputStream. Also the bytes array in above code are as it is passed for download. Why is data getting corrupted?

Comment: You're writing the entire request.

Comment: Yes, I am writing entire request because in request parameters there is only one input which is file. request.getParts() gives me empty collection. So I am not using it.

Comment: That's great, but you might want to take a look at what you're actually writing--that's what I would have done *first*, determine *how* it's being correupted. Consider using something like [Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) or equivalent.

Comment: Thanks.. I wanted to write inputStream data, but once inputStream is copied into fileOutputStream, it becomes empty. is.read(bytes) returns -1 (it returns how many bytes read). So IOUtils.copy(is, fos);
from above code makes "is" empty. And reads nothing in bytes[] array. This was the reason why file was getting corrupted. Now issue is solved, there is no need to create Temporary file and fileoutputStream. We can directly read bytes[] array using inputStream and can use "Content-Length" header to create byte array of that size.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be the data length you are reading. I had similar problem and posted on this issue link
[Java: Binary File Upload using Restlet + Apache Commons FileUpload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28328766/java-binary-file-upload-using-restlet-apache-commons-fileupload/51509769#51509769)

Hope this helps

Comment: Add the relevant content from your link to the body of your answer.